# Avoiding packet loss on a 800+ Mpbs data stream

Tags: networking, ethernet, bandwidth, packet-loss

At the highest level of abstraction, I am trying to send 800 Mbit/s from a hardware instrument to a 'normal windows computer' over a dedicated ethernet connection. But if I do so, I experience significant packet loss. 400 Mbit/s does still come through with (virtually) no lost packets. I am trying to find out what is causing the packets to be lost, and if there is something (hardware or software) I can adjust to tackle this. The rate at which I can transfer the data sets the rate at which I can resolve something happening in the device under test with the instrument; making this as fast as possible is my goal.

With a few more details, I am constantly streaming data at a specific transfer rate from a [Zurich Instruments lockin-amplifier](https://www.zhinst.com/europe/en/products/uhfli-lock-in-amplifier) to a Windows 10 Enterprise computer with 64 GB of RAM and an Intel Xeon 4110 CPU. To do this, I am using using a 1 Gbps ethernet port on the hardware device (see connectivity under [specifications](https://www.zhinst.com/europe/en/products/uhfli-lock-in-amplifier#specifications)). The host computer uses a Intel I210-T1 Ethernet Adapter to which no other devices are connected. I am using a CAT7 Ethernet cable.

The transfer rate can be set on the instrument in a few dedicated steps, which roughly correspond to transfer rates of 200, 400, and 800 Mbit/s (also slower and faster, which we can ignore for now).

Out of the box I was able to reach about 200 MBit/s of transfer rate without the instrument reporting packet loss. Following the [manual, page 44](https://docs.zhinst.com/pdf/ziUHF_UserManual.pdf) I have set up a static IP address and I have enabled jumbo frames, increasing the UDP frame size to 9014 bytes. If I do that, I can increase the transfer rate to 400 Mbit/s without losing packages.

If I instead follow an older blog [blog](https://blogs.zhinst.com/brunok/high-data-rates/) by the makers of the instrument and set the UDP frame size to 4088 bytes, I also reach 400 Mbit/s.

Based on this set of information, would anyone have an idea of how I could further investigate and optimize this connection?

I am but a simple physicist and networking is a rather new domain to me, but I am willing to learn and tweak things. I imagine there must also be better tools to investigate the packet loss rather than looking at a counter of lost packets on the instrument, which is what I am doing now.

**Post is edited based on the feedback in the comments; switched from a Realtek chipset to an Intel chipset for the ethernet connection**

Comment: You mention your network card has a realtek chipset  First thing Id try is replacing that interface with something else - a caed with an Intel chip fir example. Realtek are known for crappy hardware, and also hardware that creates a lot of unneccessary IO load.

Comment: Okay, I was already a bit worried by that. Other than the network card, the motherboard also has two ethernet ports, which correspond to an Intel I219-LM and an Intel I210 chipset. Would those be more suited? I can free those up and make sure the instrument is the only thing using those ports.

Comment: Almost certainly.  I dont know the i219-lm off-hand, but the l210 is fairly common and Id run a server on it without hesitation.

Comment: Thank you for that recommendation; I've implemented it and updated the main post. It seems to have stabilized the 400Mbps transfer with jumbo frames of 9k, but 800 still leads to significant packet loss. But I should also entertain the thought that the problem is on the instrument side, so I will reach out to their support as well.

Comment: You don't usually need jumbo frames to reach 1 GBit/s. So I'd say it's time to contact Zurich Instruments. This is clearly a problem with the device.

Comment: Your CPU is also rather slow by today’s standards. Have you checked whether it is overloaded when operating the software at high data rates?

Comment: I will do that (contact them), thank you! The CPU seems to be okay at about 20% utilization, so I don't think that is it, unless it is capping how much the network is allowed to take up somewhere in a setting I do not know about.

Comment: Before you comtact them, are you able yo  an alternative ethernet cable? (Also  if there is a structured wiring system involved are you able to plug the devices directly in to each other on ethernet, and also try it in another location in case there is rf interference ir a cabling issue)